# how to resolve "WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement"?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello
I am writing an android application, but as I do run this application, the following application generates and application doesn't appear on the windows,
please help .. !!!!
I will appreciate if I get right solution ,,,,,,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To resolve this warning add

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

to the `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Replace 4 with the lowest number of SDK version you want to support.